# How maintain the order of keys in Java properties file?

Tags: grails, groovy, gradle

I have Groovy code to read the property file and change the values and then write it to same file.

```
def props = new Properties()
File propsFile = new File('C:/Groovy/config.properties')
props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())

props.each { key, value ->

    if("${key}" == "ABC"){
        props.setProperty("${key}", "XYZ")

    }

}
props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
```

When I write the properties to file it change the order of the keys. Is there any way to maintain the same order as initial file.

I'm new to groovy please can some one give the suggestion to this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I checked the `Properties` class and it turns out it extends `Hashtable` which doesn't make any guarantees as to the ordering of its elements. So that's why the output file has the keys mixed up.

In my opinion you'd have to override at least two methods: `put`, which is called for every property (in order they occur), and `keys` which is called during saving. You'd simply use this class instead of `Properties` then.

```
import java.util.*;

public class OrderedProperties extends Properties {
    private final LinkedHashSet<Object> keyOrder = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    @Override
    public synchronized Enumeration<Object> keys() {
        return Collections.enumeration(keyOrder);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized Object put(Object key, Object value) {
        keyOrder.add(key);
        return super.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

I just tested it in your scenario and it works fine, but I surely didn't think of all possible cases. We are extending `Hashtable` here (beware!), not an usual decision I'd say...

Comment: I found this has no effect and the order is not maintained

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use decorated properties:

```
class SortedProperties extends Properties {

    @Override
    public synchronized Enumeration keys() {
        Enumeration keysEnum = super.keys();

        Vector keyList = new Vector();
        while (keysEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
            keyList.add(keysEnum.nextElement());
        }
        keyList.sort()

        return keyList.elements();
    }
}
```

Comment: The request was to write the properties file preserving the original order. Your solution is sorting the keys in alphabetical order and will likely be different than the original properties file