# How can I modify a particular line in a file without deleting the existing data using Java?

Tags: java, file

I need to change the values in a file which has more than 30 lines and each line has a data like:
ENABLE_TLS=true
PSWD_MIN_LENGTH=8

Here, let us consider this as a key and value pair, and I needed to change only the value for the 2nd line alone, without deleting the 1st line. Can someone help me how can I do this??

I have tried bufferedwriter, but it is replacing all the lines.

My expectation is:
I need to modify only a particular key's value and the remaining lines should not get deleted

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My guess is you will need to use [RandomAccessFile API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) or something like it.

Comment: You can use a [string list](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/40-string-list)

Comment: *each line has a data like: ENABLE_TLS=true PSWD_MIN_LENGTH=8* That's *one* line or two?

Comment: Like this key & value pair, it has total of 30 lines

Comment: I'm not sure if that has answered my question . Let's assume if you have one key and one value per line . In that case the answer does answer your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your description of the data sounds like Java `Properties`. If you are certain that all the data in that file takes the form `key=value` you could read it in as a `Properties` object, update the value for the key in question, and write it back to the file.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try (FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("/path/to/file")) {
   properties.load(inputStream);
}

properties.put("PSWD_MIN_LENGTH", 12);

try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file")) {
   properties.store(outputStream, null);
}
```

BEWARE: there is no guarantee that the order of the key/value entries in the file will be maintained (they probably won't). If you are looking for a `Properties` implementation that will maintain the order, maybe this SO answer will do the trick (UNTESTED!) [How maintain the order of keys in Java properties file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160293/how-maintain-the-order-of-keys-in-java-properties-file)